# Python Mechanize select value from <select> box

Tags: python, mechanize-python

I'm trying to use Mechanize to fill and submit a form, but I'm not able to fill select boxes, as it throws errors. How do I set value for select boxes before submitting it?

Comment: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select a form, and set the value you want using item assignemnt `browser[...] = [...]`.

```
b = mechanize.Browser()
b.open(url)
b.select_form(nr=0)
b['select_name_attribute'] = ['option_value']  # <-----
b.submit()
```